# Better Way To Write This Button? Angular

Tags: angular, button

I have written this save/download CSV file button for a modal in Angular. It works fine with no errors, but in Visual Studio, the component that it is in is a yellow colour and has not changed to white after writing the button. Thanks

```
<button type="button" class="mat-primary" mat-raised-button 
[mat-dialog-close] (click)="saveFileAs()">Save</button>
```

The yellow Component is the one in the middle in this screenshot -
[Screenshot of yellow Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRcA2.png)

Comment: `<button type="button" color="primary" mat-raised-button 
mat-dialog-close (click)="saveFileAs()">Save</button>` would be the "best way", but still, your button is okay. What do you mean by visual studio and the yellow/white color ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added a screenshot to my question, of the yellow component in Visual Studio.

Comment: That's what git does after you modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, my understanding is - the Component will be yellow if code has been changed or added in the Component, until the changes have been committed.

I have just committed the changes and now the Component has changed to white (how it should be).